# $F$ characteristic $0$ and $f(X) \in F[X]$ irreducible over $F$ imply $f(X)$ has distinct roots...why must $F$ be of characteristic $0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, roots, irreducible-polynomials

I have a question on this simple corollary from *Abstract Algebra* by Saracino:

> **Corollary 24.11** If $F$ is of characteristic $0$ and $f(X) \in F[X]$ is irreducible over $F$, then $f(X)$ has distinct roots.

> **Proof.** If the leading coefficient of $f(X)$ is $c_n \neq 0$ then the leading coefficient of $f'(X)$ is $nc_n \neq 0$ (since $F$ is of characteristic $0$), so $f'(X)$ is not the zero polynomial. Thus $f(X)$ has distinct roots.

Why do we need the characteristic of $F$ to be $0$? I assume here that $n \neq 0$ because otherwise we'd have $f(X) = c_0$ for some $c_0 \in F$ (and in this book, the term "irreducible" is only defined for nonconstant polynomials). Then $n \neq 0$ and $c_n \neq 0$ imply that $nc_n \neq 0$, since $F$ is a field and hence does not have any nonzero zero-divisors. (The book does not explicitly state that $F$ is a field, but I assume it must be since "characteristic" in this book is defined only for fields.)  So I'm not seeing how the characteristic of $F$ matters here.

Comment: It depends what you mean by $n\neq 0$. It can be a nonzero formal power of a term in a polynomial, but after differentiating it can equal $0$ as the element $n\in F$. That's where you need that $n\neq 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Bennie: Okay, so I think my issue was in mistaking $n$ (a nonnegative integer) for an element of $F$, which in general is not the case. So I should be interpreting $nc_n$ as $c_n + c_n + \cdots + c_n$ ($n$ times), which could be zero in characteristic $p \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the characteristic of $F$ divides $n$, then, in $F$, $n=0$. So, $nc_n=0$ too.

For instance, if the characteristic of $F$ is $2$ and if $F(x)=x^4$, then $F'(x)=4x^3=0$.

Comment: Hmm...so if the characteristic of $F$ divides $\text{deg}(f(X))$ then $\text{deg}(f(X)) = 0$? And so my assumption that $f(X)$ is nonconstant was wrong?

Comment: No: $\deg(f(X))$ is a non-negative integer. It's not an element of $F$. For instance $deg(X^4)=4$ over *any* field.

Comment: Ok well $n$ is the degree of $f(X)$ (since $c_n$ is the leading coefficient), and you wrote "If the characteristic of $F$ divides $n$", so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Suppose that $f(X)=X^4\in F[x]$. Then $f'(X)=4X^3$. But, in $F$, $4$ times anything is $0$, since$$4\times a=\overbrace{a+a}^{\phantom0=0}+\overbrace{a+a}^{\phantom0=0}=0.$$So, $4X^3$ is $0<$ for any value of $X$.

Comment: Ok I think I'm understanding now. So basically in characteristic $p \neq 0$, we can have a nonconstant polynomial whose formal derivative is the zero polynomial (because the leading coefficient of $f'(X)$ might be a multiple of the characteristic).

Comment: Your comments make more sense now. So $nc_n$ should be interpreted as adding $n$ copies of $c_n$ together, not multiplying two elements of $F$ (since $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ need not be an element of $F$)...that makes sense!